# oAuth 2.0 Grant Type User/Password in backend background process: Where to get password from

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I am writing an app that has to connect to an external API which uses oAuth 2.0 with the Grant Type User/Password. In my backend I want to e.g. do an API call every 24h.

I have my Client id/secret and would store them in environment variables.

To retrieve the user authentication token I also need an user-id and a password.
Is there any secure way for generating an user access token and making these API calls without the user entering his password by storing it in some form in the database?

I thought of the following:

1. Plain Text: Store the password in the DB in Plain Text. insecure when database is breached
2. Hashing it: If I used the normal approach for passwords by hashing + salting it (and just compare the hashed values when signing in with a password) I would not be able to use it to sign in to the api because I couldn't undo the hashing
3. Public encryption: Just encode them with a "public" encryption key that is stored in some environment variable in the backend - this is not much safer than plain text right?

What is the recommended process to get an oAuth 2.0 User/password Grant Type authentication key in a background service?

Comment: Did you figure out what to do? I have the same question

Comment: Im pretty sure it’s not meant for that. The idea is that you should only be able to communicate with server after the user inputted his password. Maybe the other grant types are a better fit. In my case I used a different approach: I could fetch the data using a web-hook that the API offered.